# Find location of shell script (or symbolic link) from shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, which

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a shell script or a symbolic link (I can't remember which one - and I'm not sure how to tell what it is) called `pbar` that runs pianobar.  So, to be explicit, from a shell, I can type `pbar` and pianobar (the program) fires up.  I am trying to find the location of this file.  I have tried doing the following,

```
which pbar
ls /usr/bin | grep ^pb
ls /usr/local/bin | grep ^pb
```

and checked the directory where I store my shell scripts and I think all the other locations on my `$PATH`.  Still I can't track down this file or link - is there some other location / method I should be using?  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `alias`?

Comment: Try `type pbar` or `command -v pbar`

Comment: @DavidPostill omg fantastic, I had no idea of this program, but you are totally right it was aliased, please post as answer if youre inclinded.

Comment: @EricRenouf that also works, sorry guys I am quite ignorant of all the linux commands

Comment: This highlights a lengthy post on U&L about why not to use `which`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then for all you wanted to know and more about it

Comment: @EricRenouf excellent! another SE site to sign up too, thanks for the liink and help

Comment: @slickrickulicious Answer posted ;)

Comment: @EricRenouf that linked answer is a gem, makes me feel specially dumb though, since there are so many solutions to the problem I had...

Comment: @slick None born knowing everything. The answer there starts from the 78 :) Remember when you have time to write in your shell `help`... and continue with `man bash` or man whatever else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Still I can't track down this file or link

One other option to consider is an `alias`.

---

#### alias

> Create an alias, aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word
>   when it is used as the first word of a simple command.
>
> ...
>
> Without arguments or with the -p option, alias prints the list of
>   aliases on the standard output in a form that allows them to be reused
>   as input.

Source [alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) - Create an alias, aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.

Answer (score 4):

A valid helper in bash is `type` <sup>[[1](http://ss64.com/bash/type.html)]</sup>

```
   type pbar
```

It will answer if it is an alias, a command, a function or a built in command.

Comment: yea this is another one I came across in that links, thanks also for the `man bash`, quite a lot there